# SilverStripe Userform module keeps showing internal server error

Tags: silverstripe

I am currently working on a website and I just started using SilverStripe. I have installed the [UserForms module](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-userforms).

When I try to make a `UserDefinedForm` page it shows an `Internal Server Error` right away. If I close the page and go back to the same page it shows me that the page is added, but when I try to open it, it shows the same error again.

When I searched for this error others have said it is because some JavaScript files are missing, but when I checked mine everything was in there.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you install this with composer? What is the Error? and lastly you did a dev/build right?

Comment: I have not installed this with a composer. The error is just: "Internal Server Error"
I have done dev/build and flush=all but none of it helps! The problem keeps coming back.

Comment: Install with composer... I'd bet this is caused by it being the wrong version... composer sort of sorts that out for but you *must* add the error here if you want help... https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/getting_started/installation/common_problems/

Comment: Thanks Barry, i will try to install with the composer, one fast question.. Do I need to reinstall everything again to make it work? (like the whole CMS)

Comment: well yes, it's not a mistake that silverstripe "download" links are now harder to find that the large text with the "copy" button that will install via composer.  But if you just post the error then you can be sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This basically means there was an error and you're not in (really) development mode - setting development mode in your config file does not change anything. If this is the case, try putting SilverStripe in dev mode by adding this:
**_config.php**

```
require_once("conf/ConfigureFromEnv.php"); //add this row
```

**_ss_environment.php**

```
define('SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE', 'dev');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

define('SS_DATABASE_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('SS_DATABASE_USERNAME', '');// you can leave this empty if you defined this in your _config.php
define('SS_DATABASE_PASSWORD', '');// you can leave this empty if you defined this in your _config.php
```

The `_config.php` file is located at the `mysite` folder. The `_ss_environment.php` file should be created at the root of your project.
When you've added this, you should flush and a readable error should appear.